# Assigning return value from Powershell script to a Groovy variable

Tags: powershell, jenkins, groovy

I have a Groovy script that runs a separate Powershell script as part of a Jenkins pipeline. The Powershell script returns a value (`int`) and I intend to use that value in the Groovy script by assigning it to a variable but the groovy variable is always evaluated to null. Code below, edited for brevity.

**Powershell Script**

```
#Some actions...
$foo = 0
return $foo
```

Returns (when run manually in Powershell):

```
0
```

**Groovy Script**

```
stage('StageX'){
    //Some actions...
    def return_val = powershell "Path\\to\\script\\someScript.ps1"
    echo return_val
    if (return_val == 0){
        //Do things...
    }
}
```

Returns:

```
null
```

I know that the script actually runs as it performs other actions that are apparent when the Groovy script runs, I just can't seem to get Groovy to pick up the return value of the Powershell script.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass it the `returnStatus` parameter:

```
    def return_val = powershell script: "Path\\to\\script\\someScript.ps1", returnStatus: true
```

See the documentation for more information https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2017/07/26/powershell-pipeline/

Answer (score 0):

Im kinda to new to powershell but what can be expected from a 0. Zero value. Nothing.

```
if (return_val == Null){
        //Do things...
    }
```

Have you tested this? Do you get another values back beside 0?