# Save powershell return value in a Jenkins Variable

Tags: powershell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a scripted pipeline in Jenkins and I am calling a powershell script to generate links to files in onedrive so I can mail them using the plug-in in the next step. I have tried using the following to get this done

`def return_val = powershell script: "Path\\to\\script\\someScript.ps1", returnStatus: true` based on this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64462160/assigning-return-value-from-powershell-script-to-a-groovy-variable)

However, I get

> Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
> hudson7145251072251175654.node() is applicable for argument types:
> (hudson7145251072251175654$_run_closure1) values:
> [hudson7145251072251175654$_run_closure1@46271dd6] Possible solutions:
> use([Ljava.lang.Object;), notify(), wait(), run(), run(), any()

This is the powershell script I am using.

```
#Config Variables
$SiteURL = "https://company-my.sharepoint.com/personal/name"
$FolderURL= "/Documents/Desktop" #Folder's Site Relative Path
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Interactive
$Context.Credentials = $Credentials
$linklist =[System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
linkfunction {
    $FolderItems = @(Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $FolderURL -ItemType File)
    foreach($item in $folderItems)
      {
        $linklist.Add($item.Name)
        Write-Host $linklist
      }
    return $linklist
```

Comment: This seems to be a Groovy issue only as the `powershell` call looks correct. Please add more of the Groovy script, the actual cause of the problem propably is somewhere else.

Comment: Also, what is the expected value of `return_val`? Are you trying to return an `ArrayList` from PowerShell to Groovy?

Comment: @zett42 Actually there could be more than one files..I was hoping to solve that issue later. Yes it is an `ArrayList` . Let me update the groovy code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`powershell returnStatus: true` only returns the numeric *exit code* from the PowerShell script (which is 0 on success but could be set to a different value by calling `exit 42` from PowerShell for instance).

To return strings or other complex data from PowerShell to Groovy, you need to use `powershell returnStdout: true`. This gives you the whole output from PowerShell that is written to the *success output stream* as a single, possibly multiline string.

A simplified PowerShell script:

```sh
$list = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
$null = $list.Add('foo\bar')
$null = $list.Add('baz')
$list  # Implicit output, a "return" statement is not required in PowerShell
```

Assigning to `$null` makes sure that the return value of `ArrayList.Add()` doesn't end as (unwanted) output of the PowerShell script.

This outputs each array element on its own line:

```text
foo\bar
baz
```

To turn the PowerShell output back into an array on the Groovy side we can do:

```java
def return_val = powershell script: "Path\\to\\script\\someScript.ps1", returnStdout: true
def return_array = return_val.split(/\r?\n/)
```

Here `return_val` is a single multiline string. Using the [`String.split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method we turn it back into an array and store it in variable `return_array`.

`String.split()` expects a regular expression, that defines where to split the string. The RegEx `\r?\n` splits on both Windows `\r\n` and Unix-style `\n` line ends. I'm using [slashy string](https://www.groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_slashy_string) literal to avoid having to escape the backslashes, very handy for RegEx patterns.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, just change the **returnStatus** to **returnStdout** and save it in a variable.
You can change your code to this

```
return_val = powershell script: "Path\\to\\script\\someScript.ps1", returnStdout : true
echo "{$return_val}"
```